# SignalR Angular Client throws errror on start()

Tags: angular, signalr

I am trying to use `@microsoft/signalr` in my Angular 11 project with NGRX. I have implemented my connection method in an action like this:

```js
connectToHub = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(SanctionsActions.connectToHub),
      withLatestFrom(this.authService.getAccessTokenSilently()),
      map(([action, token])=> {
        let options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
          accessTokenFactory: () => {
            return token
          }
        };

        let connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        //.withUrl(`${environment.baseUrl}/api/sanctions/v1/ws/quickscreen`)
        .withUrl(`https://localhost:44300/api/sanctions/v1/ws/quickscreen`)
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
        .build();
        
        connection.on("receiveQuickScreenResults", (results) => {
          this.store$.dispatch(SanctionsActions.quickScreenSearchComplete({result: results}))
        });

        connection.start().then(x => console.log("Connected to SignalR.")).catch((err) => console.error(err.toString()));
        return SanctionsActions.signalrHubConnected({connection: connection});
      })
    )
  });
```

When this action runs, though. I am getting an error saying:

`sanctions.effects.ts:113 TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'connectionState' of object '[object Object]'`

and

`Utils.js:218 [2021-08-13T18:47:58.073Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot add property transport, object is not extensible`

These are things that must be happening inside the start() method, because, as you can see, I am not assigning anything to those properties.

**Stacktrace for Exceptions**

```
Utils.js:228 [2021-08-14T00:26:16.078Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: https://localhost:44300/api/sanctions/v1/ws/quickscreen/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1.
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at ngrx-store.js:851
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:842)
    at ngrx-store.js:854
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:842)
    at ngrx-store.js:854
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (ngrx-store.js:842)
    at ngrx-store.js:854
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6456
handleError @ core.js:6504
computeNextEntry @ ngrx-store-devtools.js:439
recomputeStates @ ngrx-store-devtools.js:469
(anonymous) @ ngrx-store-devtools.js:763
StoreDevtools.liftedAction$.pipe.state @ ngrx-store-devtools.js:789
_tryNext @ scan.js:49
_next @ scan.js:42
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ withLatestFrom.js:57
next @ Subscriber.js:49
observe @ Notification.js:20
dispatch @ observeOn.js:25
_execute @ AsyncAction.js:51
execute @ QueueAction.js:20
flush @ AsyncScheduler.js:33
schedule @ QueueAction.js:14
schedule @ Scheduler.js:7
schedule @ AsyncScheduler.js:21
scheduleMessage @ observeOn.js:30
_next @ observeOn.js:33
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:70
_next @ innerSubscribe.js:10
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ map.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:70
_next @ innerSubscribe.js:10
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ skip.js:21
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
next @ BehaviorSubject.js:30
next @ ngrx-store.js:134
dispatch @ ngrx-store.js:456
ngOnInit @ quick-screen.component.ts:29
callHook @ core.js:2526
callHooks @ core.js:2495
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.js:2446
refreshView @ core.js:9460
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshComponent @ core.js:10616
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:9242
refreshView @ core.js:9495
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshComponent @ core.js:10616
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:9242
refreshView @ core.js:9495
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:9559
tickRootContext @ core.js:10790
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:10815
detectChanges @ core.js:22865
tick @ core.js:29655
(anonymous) @ core.js:29536
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.js:28674
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
run @ core.js:28528
next @ core.js:29535
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25944
checkStable @ core.js:28596
onHasTask @ core.js:28691
hasTask @ zone.js:426
_updateTaskCount @ zone.js:447
_updateTaskCount @ zone.js:274
runTask @ zone.js:195
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:582
invokeTask @ zone.js:491
invokeTask @ zone.js:1600
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1626
Show 51 more frames
Utils.js:228 [2021-08-14T00:26:16.695Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
Utils.js:218 [2021-08-14T00:26:16.696Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: TypeError: Cannot add property transport, object is not extensible
ConsoleLogger.log @ Utils.js:218
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:318
step @ HttpConnection.js:41
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:22
rejected @ HttpConnection.js:14
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.js:28674
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1276
invokeTask @ zone.js:406
onInvokeTask @ core.js:28661
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:582
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:565
scheduleTask @ zone.js:396
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:283
scheduleTask @ zone.js:386
scheduleTask @ zone.js:221
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:241
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1266
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1204
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1120
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1456
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
Ctor.then @ zone.js:1455
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1171
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1120
(anonymous) @ FetchHttpClient.js:25
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
step @ FetchHttpClient.js:25
fulfilled @ FetchHttpClient.js:23
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.js:28674
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1276
invokeTask @ zone.js:406
onInvokeTask @ core.js:28661
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:582
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:565
scheduleTask @ zone.js:396
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:283
scheduleTask @ zone.js:386
scheduleTask @ zone.js:221
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:241
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1266
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1204
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1120
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1456
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
Ctor.then @ zone.js:1455
(anonymous) @ VM413:1
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1465
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:975
(anonymous) @ FetchHttpClient.js:122
step @ FetchHttpClient.js:51
(anonymous) @ FetchHttpClient.js:32
(anonymous) @ FetchHttpClient.js:26
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ FetchHttpClient.js:22
FetchHttpClient.send @ FetchHttpClient.js:86
DefaultHttpClient.send @ DefaultHttpClient.js:47
HttpClient.post @ HttpClient.js:32
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:352
step @ HttpConnection.js:41
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:22
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:16
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ HttpConnection.js:12
HttpConnection.getNegotiationResponse @ HttpConnection.js:330
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:263
step @ HttpConnection.js:41
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:22
step @ HttpConnection.js:26
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:22
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:16
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ HttpConnection.js:12
HttpConnection.startInternal @ HttpConnection.js:232
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:117
step @ HttpConnection.js:41
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:22
(anonymous) @ HttpConnection.js:16
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ HttpConnection.js:12
HttpConnection.start @ HttpConnection.js:105
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:187
step @ HubConnection.js:33
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:14
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:8
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ HubConnection.js:4
HubConnection.startInternal @ HubConnection.js:175
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:157
step @ HubConnection.js:33
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:14
(anonymous) @ HubConnection.js:8
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1387
__awaiter @ HubConnection.js:4
HubConnection.startWithStateTransitions @ HubConnection.js:144
HubConnection.start @ HubConnection.js:140
(anonymous) @ sanctions.effects.ts:113
_next @ map.js:29
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ withLatestFrom.js:57
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ filter.js:33
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
(anonymous) @ ngrx-store-devtools.js:803
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_tryNext @ scan.js:55
_next @ scan.js:42
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ withLatestFrom.js:57
next @ Subscriber.js:49
observe @ Notification.js:20
dispatch @ observeOn.js:25
_execute @ AsyncAction.js:51
execute @ QueueAction.js:20
flush @ AsyncScheduler.js:33
schedule @ QueueAction.js:14
schedule @ Scheduler.js:7
schedule @ AsyncScheduler.js:21
scheduleMessage @ observeOn.js:30
_next @ observeOn.js:33
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:70
_next @ innerSubscribe.js:10
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ map.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
notifyNext @ mergeMap.js:70
_next @ innerSubscribe.js:10
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ skip.js:21
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
next @ BehaviorSubject.js:30
next @ ngrx-store.js:134
dispatch @ ngrx-store.js:456
ngOnInit @ quick-screen.component.ts:29
callHook @ core.js:2526
callHooks @ core.js:2495
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.js:2446
refreshView @ core.js:9460
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshComponent @ core.js:10616
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:9242
refreshView @ core.js:9495
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshEmbeddedViews @ core.js:10570
refreshView @ core.js:9469
refreshComponent @ core.js:10616
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:9242
refreshView @ core.js:9495
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:9559
tickRootContext @ core.js:10790
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:10815
detectChanges @ core.js:22865
tick @ core.js:29655
(anonymous) @ core.js:29536
invoke @ zone.js:372
onInvoke @ core.js:28674
invoke @ zone.js:371
run @ zone.js:134
run @ core.js:28528
next @ core.js:29535
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25944
checkStable @ core.js:28596
onHasTask @ core.js:28691
hasTask @ zone.js:426
_updateTaskCount @ zone.js:447
_updateTaskCount @ zone.js:274
runTask @ zone.js:195
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:582
invokeTask @ zone.js:491
invokeTask @ zone.js:1600
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1626
Show 141 more frames
sanctions.effects.ts:113 TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'connectionState' of object '[object Object]'
(anonymous) @ sanctions.effects.ts:113
invoke @ zone.js:372
```

And here are the server logs for that request:

```
IIS Express is running.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubProtocolResolver[1]
      Registered SignalR Protocol: json, implemented by Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\src\kinectify\repo\apis\sanctions\api
JWT Token Received.
JWT Token Received.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager[1]
      New connection Hyb_RDLMxSJkjRJl2lTSaQ created.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher[10]
      Sending negotiation response.
```

Comment: please share the log and a full stack trace

Comment: No problem @ModarNa, I updated the post